# Matrix Access from within a function

Tags: c, arrays, string, character, header-files

I have a large number of strings that I need to store in a character array and I need to be able to loop through all of the strings.

Furthermore, these strings won't be changing so I want the matrix to be permanent and preferably stored in a header file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm working in C and don't know the best way to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable definitions in a header might not be such a good idea, consider alternatives:

```
// source.c contains
const char *const strings[] = {
    "string1", "string2", NULL 
};

// source.h contains
extern const char *const strings[];

// include source.h anywhere and loop through the strings like this:
for (const char *const *str = strings; *str != NULL; ++str)
    // use *str
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a two level pointer:

```
   #define NUMBER_OF_ROWS 10
   #define MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARS_IN_STRING 255

   char *strings = (char**)calloc(NUMBER_OF_ROWS * sizeof(char));
   const char copy_string[] = "default string";

   for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
   {
      strings[i] = (char*)calloc(MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARS_IN_STRING);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; i++)
   {
      strcpy(strings[i], copy_string);
   }
```

This is assuming you are using ANSI C